# KeyDown event listener seems to not work when button items are added to WinForm

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a basic WinForm that I am working with. I have set the `FormBorderStyle` as `None` and I am using a `KeyDown` event on the form to check if the Escape key is pressed and, if it is, it closes the form.

Everything works perfectly until I add a button. It appears that the issue is the button automatically gains focus during runtime and, as events only register for whatever item has focus (the button doesn't have a `KeyDown` listener--the form does), it doesn't close when I press the Escape key.

I looked at the WinForm object (`[System.Windows.Forms.Form]`) and searched the properties and methods in reference to focus and most of them are `get;` methods and `bool` queries. Ideally, it would work if there was something like a `$form.StartsWithFocus = $true` `set;` property but, unfortunately, from what I saw, that isn't the case.

Clicking outside of the button but still within the form doesn't seems to change the focus over to the form.

Here is a simplified version of my WinForm. Is it something I'm missing?

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'
$form.Add_KeyDown({
    if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {
        $form.Close()
        }
    })

$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
$form.ShowDialog()
```

This above will open a small form in the middle of the screen. If you press the Escape key, it closes. Simple.

---

However, when I add the button, it stops working.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Add_KeyDown({
    if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {
        $form.Close()
        }
    })

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = '20,20'
$button.Size = '100,30'

$form.Controls.Add($button)

$form.Add_Shown({$form.Activate()})
$form.ShowDialog()
```

If you run this (above), pressing the Escape key does nothing.

So, where is this going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: $form.KeyPreview = $true! I knew it was something I was overlooking. That was exactly it. I have that on several of my other tools and apps but I forgot about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A form doesn't receive a KeyDown event if one of its controls has the focus unless you set the property [KeyPreview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) to true.

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Add_KeyDown({
    if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {
        $form.Close()
        }
    })
$form.KeyPreview = $true
......
```

Another possibility is to set the CancelButton of your form to the instance of the newly created button and omit the close code (but you probably still need the KeyPreview setting for other tasks so.... )

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')

$form = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Add_KeyDown({
#    if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") {
#        $form.Close()
#        }
    })

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.Location = '20,20'
$button.Size = '100,30'
$form.CancelButton = $button
#$form.KeyPreview = $true
```